# Faster way to find string in HTML

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Good evening,

I made a program to make a request to a website with certain headers, etc. and I'm checking to see if the page contains a certain string. The problem is that it's taking about a minute for each website. I want a way to optimize it if it's possible. I'm fairly sure that the problem is reader.ReadToEnd. I'm guessing there's way that I can read until I find a match. Here is the code, thank you very much.

```
foreach (string s in lines)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(s);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Host = s;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Proxy = null;

    string source;
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            source = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (source.Contains("xxxxx"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(s);
            }
        }

    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How large are those websites? A minute seems excessive.

Comment: They're fairly large. I was testing on sites such as Google.

Comment: Google.com is about 150K, that's not large. That takes less than a second in my browser. How long does loading take in your browser? Does it take a minute there, too?

Comment: No, it's about one second in my browser. Would the problem be caused because I'm reading directly from a text file? I don't see any other reason it'd take that long.

Comment: Can you do some real time measurements? In code?

Comment: Okay, so I tested it again today and it's a lot faster, but it's still taking about three seconds per URL when I timed it. Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If downloading a single page takes long, there is not much you can do. However, guessing that the resource that makes it take so long is not on your end, you can request all those sites in parallel. That way, if one takes 3 seconds, with a little luck, *all* will take 3 seconds.

First, you need to put your downloading into a method of it's own:

```
private static bool SiteContains(string url, string searchText)
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(s);
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.Host = s;
  request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
  request.Method = "GET";
  request.Proxy = null;

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
   {
     var source = reader.ReadToEnd();
     return source.Contains(searchText);
   }
}
```

Please note that I skipped error handling for the example, you will need to add some.

You can then use PLinQ to handle your list in parallel:

```
var results = lines.AsParallel().Select( line => new { Site = line, Result = SiteContains(line, "xxxxx") } );

foreach(var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Site={0}, Result={1}", result.Site, result.Result);
}
```

The actuall downloading and checking will be in parallel, the foreach-loop in the end is just for output after the fact. You may want to replace it with a Windows Forms solution like a listbox or messageboxes.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the answer. I tried it out, and it might be the way I set up the loading of websites, but it's just printing out every website.

Comment: Well, it should print the URL and either true or false depending of the existance of your search text. If you have problems with it, try to minimize the code to an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't try scraping Google, or you're going to be in a world of pain.
Especially don't scrape Google and parallelise the requests as has been suggested. Hitting them, or anyone with as many requests as possible, as quickly as you can, is a sure way to get caught.

Secondly, I assume you're looking for something more complex than xxxxxxx. If you need to do any parsing, try the HTMLAgilityPack in NuGet.

Thirdly, if you do want to streamline this, have one thread doing the downloading to a local location, then, in a second thread, process a queue of the files to do the searching. This will especially help during your testing, where you're probably re-running this code repeatedly until you get it right.